# How to input a list of values to a specific column using batch update in googles spreadsheet api, in python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to input data into a column with googlesheets api in python. Currently using both append and updatecells it only allows you to input the data into a specific row. In the example below that would input the value 5 into 3 different columns of the same row. (similar output with append. I would like all 3 values to be input into the same column in consecutive rows.

```
"updateCells": {
            "rows": [
                {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "numberValue": 5
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "numberValue": 5
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "numberValue": 5
                        }
                    }
                ]
                }
            ],
            "range": {
                "startColumnIndex": 10,
                "endColumnIndex": 11,
                "startRowIndex": 0
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredValue"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put a list to a column of a Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In your request body, 3 values of `5` are put into a row of 3 columns. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample, "Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate" is used.

```py
service = ###  # Please use your client.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please put your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_id = "0"  # Please put the sheet ID of the sheet you want to use.
sample_value = [1, 2, 3] # This is a sample value.

requests = {
    "updateCells": {
        "rows": [
            {"values": {"userEnteredValue": {"numberValue": e}}}
            for e in sample_value
        ],
        "range": {"startColumnIndex": 10, "startRowIndex": 0},
        "fields": "userEnteredValue",
    }
}
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body={"requests": requests}
).execute()
```

- When this script is run, the values of `[1, 2, 3]` is put to the cells "K1:K3" of "Sheet1".

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample, "Method: spreadsheets.values.append" is used.

```py
service = ###  # Please use your client.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please put your Spreadsheet ID.
sample_value = [1, 2, 3] # This is a sample value.

service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    body={"values": [sample_value], "majorDimension": "COLUMNS"},
    valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
    range="Sheet1!K1",
).execute()
```

- When this script is run, the values of `[1, 2, 3]` is appended to the columne "K".

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Comment: The first solution offered worked perfectly. Note for future users I have not tested the second solution.